Is libertarian free will incoherent?
This is getting long. Here's the TL;DR;

The determinism-randomness dilemma has been discussed a lot both on this forum and in philosophy as a whole.
What I was trying to get at here is that the concept of Libertarian Free Will, even when considered by itself (and not against determinism or randomness) has severe conceptual problems.

What about "selecting" or "deciding" is agency-conferring? Even if we grant will as a third causal option, it is differentiated as a brute impulse vs anything responsibility bearing.

To the extent we can explain these "willful impulses" we are back to citing reasons, which beget questions about why we chose to give those reasons, and so on. At the end, we are left with a brute impulse.
So, even granting the existence of a third causal option ("will") it seems like at its core its just an extra-physical impulse, hardly worthy of doing any moral or deliberative work by itself.

Edit: 12/2/2024:
I realized my presentation below came across as defining away free will from the get go. The intention was to actually challenge the implication that determinism and randomness exhaust the causal landscape.
I've clarified my definitions (and adjusted the terms -- thanks Pertti) as the original ones were too vague. Hopefully that will eliminate the charge of question begging/circularity :)

I am trying to understand the coherence of libertarian (contra-causal) free will.
To define my terms (expanded to not imply I am "begging the question" against free will):

Deterministic: An event E is deterministic iff there exists a set of conditions sufficient for it to occur (i.e., sufficient set) 
Indeterministic: An event E is random iff there does not exist a sufficient set of conditions (note: we can have purely necessary conditions) 
Deliberate: When a decision D by an agent A serves as the sufficient cause of event E. 
Random: An indeterministic event E that is not deliberate.

The big question here is if the following is true (quantifying over the domain of antecedent sets of facts/conditions):

Proposition 1  "Event E is deliberate due to A choosing D" → ∃Q: "Q is sufficient for A choosing D"

With this framing, my major struggle is understanding how "A choosing D" is not the result of some combination of deterministic and random causes.
If we truly have agency then we need to have control over our decisions. This leads me to another proposition for a sufficient condition for identifying when A can be said to have decided D:

Proposition 2  IF (the set O of available options includes an option D and at least one more option other than D) and (A can provide an account/explanation of why they chose D) THEN A has decided D.

Some may argue with this definition as it excludes cases where we feel we "decide at random" (for example on a test where we don't know the answer). But I think to include "decided randomly" as "decisions" in the "deliberative" sense begs the question we are trying to resolve -- was that "random choice" really an example of you exercising agency (deliberating), or was it giving up agency and letting the neurons go their course?
If we assume Proposition 2 is true, then Proposition 1 is true within this domain. Every choice has a reason which itself must have a reason etc.
But what if we challenge that? What if you say "No, I gave you my reason but I have no reason for my reason." To me the counter is that you really didn't exercise contra-causal agency, you just played out the inevitable reasoning of your brain, which inexplicably provided you this reason for your decision.
So, when trying to understand our choices we end up going down a rabbit hole of chained reasoning (therapists make a lot of money this way ;) or we end the chain at a brute feeling/impulse (a type of brute fact).
In either case, I fail to see where we have any control above and beyond the control embedded in our neurology and acting through normal physical processes.

Example
If an agent A decides to have ketchup on their hot dog (event K), but they could have chosen another condiment (¬K) in what sense did they have such freedom to do otherwise?
If we ask A "Why did you choose K?" then A can give some reason ("I like the taste of K better") or admit to being arbitrary ("I just picked K for no reason").
But if A gave a reason, then if we "wound back the clock" the agent would still posses the preferences and antecedent conditions that led them to choose K, so they would still choose K. Their preference for K (and any environmental factors) is a sufficient condition for A choosing K. They couldn't have picked mustard in that situation.
If we say they could have chosen otherwise, under the exact same conditions, then there is a possible world accessible from the actual one where A suddenly likes mustard in that situation in instead of ketchup - but why? Where did this come from? How is this type of freedom anything like the agency we want for moral agents. If eating mustard were morally bad then we seem to be unable to fully account for why we acted morally in a given situation - at some point there will be a brute impulse driving the more sophisticated machinations of our mind.
If A has no reason, then they are just a random condiment picker (random).
Where is there a need to posit a process that somehow modulates action potentials in our neurons in in a way no pre-determined by physical laws?
--

According to your definition of “random” the proposition "E is deterministic" ∨ "E is random" has the form “A or non-A” and is always true in 2-valued logic. Therefore your whole implication is trivially true and the answer to "the big question is "Yes". Do you really mean this?

"The agent would still posses the preference that led them to choose K, so they would still choose K" is false. Consider a loaded coin toss with the odds of heads to tails, say, 2:1. The coin "possesses the preference" for heads, but it will not always land on heads. The idea that "reason" = sufficient cause is generally dubious. One can have reasons that constrain but do not determine the outcome even without probabilities. "Willed" outcome is the one brought about within those constraints. It will be "just random" by your 'definition', but so much the worse for that definition.

@Conifold your analogy is fallacious. In the example, the preference is also the reason for his action. It explains his action. And if it’s a sufficient cause and the only preference, it fully determines it. If there are other preferences, and there is no reason why his particular preference was chosen over others, then it now becomes effectively random. A coin’s particular toss landing on heads isn’t explained by a 2:1 odds ratio. Thus, the coin is still landing on heads without a sufficient reason. Only a large series of trials are explained by probabilities.

Cannot someone's will be a cause for an event, in which case the will is part of determination, rather than being a third option?

@Olivier5 yes, in a "proximate cause" sense it can be; but my interest is in the workings of the will. What I haven't seen is a description of will that doesn't end in up sounding like a synonym for random. If someone can provide such a description that would help a lot.

@JoWehler It wasn't as clear as it should have been that I was actually questioning the setup I proposed, not asserting it. In other words, what about the "will" (which I left vague) invalidates that implication?

@Syed, the 2:1 weight is specifically not a sufficient cause, and also clearly isn’t a reason!  Your coin has a preference, but on occasion it just goes “eh, I know generally heads, but this time tails”. We do not there say that the 2:1 weight is in itself the reason for voting tails, right? We say there was a process of deliberation that happened and the outcome of the process is the action, and if there is a proximal cause it’s the process rather than the weights, right?

The will thingy does work, pragmatically, in that people end up opting to consume ketchup, or not. They don't endlessly hesitate between condiment options, which to me seems like a feature of the will, a positive aspect. HOW it works seems to depend on one's character and preferences. Some of us are very intuitive, other rather analytical. It's always a bit of a mix of those two. There are different approaches to control too: I'm not control-oriented, more hands-off than most.

@SofieSelnes there is no deliberation. For a particular coin toss, whether the odds are 2:1, or 10:1, there is no cause for the coin to land on heads. It is still random. The 2:1 odds would only explain why after 1000 tosses, about 666 of them land on heads. It would not explain why the coin lands on heads next. Saying that this involves deliberation and thus a third process of free will when analogizing to your thoughts is question begging

For the sake of coherence, if I punch you in the nose to answer this question (and prove a point), then would you regard that cause of harm to be willed, random, or deterministic? Would you infer that I could inhibit such action? Would you infer that I act with malice or negligent intent? Would you assert in public or private that I should (normative) inhibit such hostile impulse? Humans and animals inhabit a context of emotional drama which does not reduce to models of the physical universe! The fact that we can reason in terms of abstract sources of cause injects confusion into the drama.

@SystemTheory metaphysically I'd consider it some combination of deterministic and random influences (just don't know neuroscience enough here) and would be experienced by you as intent (I'd infer negligent intent). What you are getting at is the moral implications - its assumed that without the idea that we "could have chosen otherwise" that we cannot pass judgement, but I disagree. Part of us being social animals is we are primed to be "norm making" to enforce mutual safety and cohesion. If your brain is faulty and violates the norms, all the worse for you unfortunately.

@Annika - I do not reject the idea that the ego (effort to govern action in the sensory context) is a function generated by a biological feedback structure. When I lift my coffee cup to drink or type on these keys my conscious perception of agency, of self, and of others, arises as the product of a subconscious process. My conscious mind can map or relate that unconscious source of cause only to conscious attributes or characteristics. Then my conscious human perceptions of agency, will, and ethical/moral judgment may or may not be the incoherent by-products of a coherent natural process.

@SystemTheory no argument from me on that :)

This question is similar to: Is free will a third option aside from chance and necessity?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Possible dup as well: What is the difference between free-will and randomness and or non-determinism?

@user80226 -- thanks! those didn't pop up as I was writing, but will take a look.

@user80226 those are helpful questions but not exact duplicates. I think my post goes in to more detail/exposition on the matter. My takeaway is that we cannot tell if we are truly freely wiling something, nor can we tell if anyone else is. However, we do have a lot of evidence that our world is causally closed under physics, so it appears that physicalism wins the day for now but we should see it as a rebuttable assumption.

Kevin Mitchell, a scientist working in the field of genetics and neuroscience, published: “Free agents. How evolution gave us free will. Princeton Press (2023)”.

His preface takes Denett as representative for the compatibilist
position: “This compatibilist view of free will is widespread among
philosophers and scientists, but it cannot explain how free will or
indeed any form of real agency can possibly exist in a deterministic
universe. […] I do not think that either the strictly deterministic
or the compatibilist position is satisfactory.”

Mitchell describes his own position: “[…] living organisms do things,
for reasons, as causal agents in their own right. They are driven
not by energy but by information. And the meaning of that
information is embodied in the structure of the system itself, based
on its history. In short, there are fundamentally distinct types of
causation at play in living organism by virtue of their
organization.”

IMO Mitchell’s book opens up the search space for an explanation of
free will within the causally closed space of scientific
explanation. Mitchell introduces biological evolution as a new
dimension when investigating agency of organisms from the cell to
higher developed animals like humans.
The principle of downward
causation - always a bit suspicious in science - appears in a new
light.
For a talk of Mitchell see here.
On request I can email a copy of the preface of Mitchell's book.


Added: I remember that Mitchell's ideas and his book were the subject of a former post on this blog.

"compatibilism ... cannot explain how free will or indeed any form of real agency can possibly exist in a deterministic universe" - this objection is trivially resolved if one views compatibilism as merely a semantic distinction with strict determinism. This would leave Mitchell's objection itself as merely a semantic disagreement - he merely rejects the compatibilist definition of free will, and says it doesn't meet the definition of "real agency" (whatever that means).

@NotThatGuy For more details please see his talk. As far as I'm concerned subsequently I read his book.

I'm having a hard time seeing Mitchell's position as anything more than dressed up determinism. Appealing to "information" and "the system" still appear to be serving the roles as objective causes of behavior vs some internal will.

"....And the meaning of that information is embodied in the structure of the system itself, based on its history." --> that is perfectly fine, but it suggests, at best, downward causation from system to parts. This type of causation can also be perfectly deterministic and therefore obviate the need to any extra cause like "will"

but maybe I'm missing something -- I unfortunately don't have time to delve deeply into one scientist's theory right now but I'll take your word on the contents you've summarized. I also get suspicious when non-physicists (especially biologists) start talking about "information" and things that are many levels below their main area of study. To date, I don't think we even know of a way to test that we are seeing downward causation or the action of embodied information.

@Annika Mitchell’s book opened-up my eyes how barren it is to discuss free will solely with terms from philosophy (of nature) like determinism, random events, “I could have done other”, agency, will etc. Mitchell's new aspect includes how species developed during their ontogenesis by continuous adaption to their environment: Which systems and algorithms did they develop to control how their drives trigger their actions? And how does their organism evaluate the corresponding feedback and decide about its further action? (1/2)

@Annika Restricted to some lines of comment I can not do better than recommending the about 12 chapters from Mitchell’s book. I for myself did profit enormously from this book. I hope not to fall back behind Mitchell’s insights in further discussions about understanding free will within the scientific frame of determinism. (2/2)

+1 and accepted for the fascinating link to Mitchell — look forward to diving in

I find the use of the word "agents" to be very evocative considering the current LLM landscape. There are LLM agents that take actions that aren't completely predictable (and are sometimes downright confounding) and are even governed by a parameter called "noise" (to increase or decrease randomness). Do these LLM agents have "free will" per Mitchell's arguments? If not, what would it take for them to have "free will"? (NB: I do not believe LLMs are "conscious" or have "free will", but they are unpredictable. The question is, are we conscious and have free will?)

That seems like a good book. Re. "downward causation", I thinks it's best understood as the causal power of systems and structures eg to achieve a certain level of resilience and self-sustainment.

@Olivier5 Mitchell discusses top-down causation i.a. in chapter 12 "Free Will", section "Some philosophical issues".

@Olivier5 yeah, I've always thought of downward causation as a sophisticated form of compatiblism

@Annika It is a metaphor, like "upward causation". There's no elevator actually involved.

@Olivier5 ^__^ lol

@JoWehler How well did he manage in that chapter? Were you convinced by his approach, or did you find something missing there, in that last stretch?

@Olivier5 The quoted section from chapter 12 brings together some concepts from the philosophy of nature with the scientific explanations developed before. The leading idea is to introduce evolution as a phenomenon in time: It builds bottom-up organism with high-level structures which a posteriori provide a top-down causality. – Currently I’m not convinced by Mitchell’s “Chapter 7: The future is not written”. And still, I have to read some remaining sections of his book.

@JoWehler I haven't read chapter 7 of course, but I like the tittle. :-) how could the future possibly get written, and by whom?

Libertarian (contra-causal) free will is a philosophical position which holds that choices (particularly human choices) are acts of will, not causally determined events. In other words, say person X comes to a fork in a road and takes the road on the left. There are two possible explanations for this event:

Determinism: turning left is the mere summation of all previous events in the universe, so X was always going to take the left road, and there is no possibility that they might ever have taken the right road.
Libertarian free will: X chose to go left, but could have chosen to go right; the event occurred as a matter of X's will, and is not bound to the summation of all previous events in the universe.

This philosophical notion doesn't depend on knowing the element or mechanism that makes free choice possible. It simply asserts that free choice is possible (somehow or other), and works from there. Nor does it make that assertion lightly, since the common  human experience is that we make choices that are seemingly free within the constraints of given situations.
The confusion in this question arises because the question presumes a deterministic worldview in which all events must have determinate causal explanations, and so it interprets the concept of 'will' (oddly) as randomness. But will isn't random; will is purposive. Randomness is merely a modern convention which models unknown effects as though they are undiscovered and unpredictable deterministic processes. Libertarian free will asserts that purposive behavior cannot be reduced to deterministic principles, known or unknown, predictable or unpredictable.

"The confusion in this question arises because the question presumes a deterministic worldview in which all events must have determinate causal explanations, and so it interprets the concept of 'will' (oddly) as randomness." -- more precisely, I cannot see what the will is actually doing that cannot be interpreted as randomness or determined by antecedent conditions.

In re Annika's comment, I think this answer could be improved by explaining interventional supernatural dualism as a possible a priori ontological framing.

@Annika: Nothing is stopping you from interpreting will as randomness, but… you have to understand that this interpretation is a belief specific to determinism  (not a fact), and LFW specifically rejects that belief. 'Random' is one of those nebbishy scapegoat words (like 'soul') that effectively boils down to: "we have no idea what's going on, but we'll give it a label so we feel better about it."  Saying something is random answers no actual question, but merely implies that there's a physicalist answer we haven't yet figured out.

@TedWrigley - fair on the random part (we don't know if true ontic randomness exists). But let's say there is no ontic randomness, then we have "willed" and "determined", but if something is willed by an agent then the agent owns that decision, no external influences forced their hand. What I debate is if we can know if we ever see such phenomena - its neurons all the way up and down as far as we know...

@gs: I'm trying to avoid invoking metaphysics directly, because LFW doesn't really go there by itself. LFW asserts the existence of will, but leaves the question of its instantiation open. You can see that as cheap handwaving or empirical skepticism, as you're inclined…

@Annika: Well, first, let's not straw-man the concept of will. Not philosopher suggests that will has to be absolutely and perfectly free; what will requires is some undetermined element couched within the contexts and structures of the physical world. You can have all the neurons you like, so long as somewhere in the system you escape or sidestep electrochemical determinacy. I think current speculations tend to look at accumulated quantum effects, but I don't really have an opinion. This is a "there are more things under heaven and earth than are spoken of …" situation.

@TedWrigley agreed on that -- if we found violations of physical laws in the brain we'd need to re-think the supervenience of the mind on the brain. There would be evidence of a purposeful (non-random) effect on our neurology that doesn't appear to be coming from prior neural events.

@TedWrigley but even if we found that, we have the introspective problem of will -- we end up in an infinite regress of reasoning or we end it with a brute "willful impulse" -- neither seems to describe the agency we want as we are still slaves to impulses

@Annika: [shrug] You seem to be arguing from counterfactuals. Our immediate perception is that we make choices, and that we could choose otherwise (LFW). The skeptic's job is to show that this isn't the case; our immediate perceptions don't have to prove themselves to be true. Maybe our immediate perception is false, but until someone shows it's false, we are obliged to take it as given. Empiricism 101…

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"we could choose otherwise" (really it is: "we could have chosen") - so, that's not a counter factual??

@mudskipper: No, it's an assertion.  It would be a counterfactual if we said we did choose otherwise,

Short answer
Yes.  I have not seen a definition of libertarian free will that clearly logically closes, and captures everything meant by libertarians about free will.
BUT -- I have not seen a definition of causation that clearly logically closes, and captures everything meant by users of "cause".
All definitions of science have suffered the same problem -- Both Popper's and Lakatos' definitions have been shown to have exceptions.
The similar failure for physicalism even has a name: Hempel's Dilemma.
Most philosophers try to gloss over the issue, but definitional shortcomings are a feature of basically every philosophic viewpoint.  This is not a fatal problem.  We get by with reasonably approximate definitions.
Longer Answer
The best description I have found is on this blog web site by the Information Philosopher, Bob Doyle, on agent causation:  https://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/agent-causality.html SEP also discusses agent causation here:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/incompatibilism-theories/#3  And Helen Steward wrote a good book outlining the plausibility of Agent Causation https://www.amazon.com/dp/0198706464.
These discussions are not quite as explicit as I think they need to be on the three preconditions needed for libertarian free will.  I consider them to be:

Our physical universe is probabilistic.  This is the dominant view of what quantum mechanics tells us, and indeterminacy is known to leverage up to be  relevant at macro scales due to chaos phenomena, so this criteria is reasonably taken as true of our world.
Our physical universe is not causally closed to agents influencing it.  Things like the near consensus that irreducibly emergent phenomena are causal, the placebo effect where our awareness is causal, the evolutionary tuning of consciousness, and every one of us experiencing our willing causing our actions every day, make this highly plausibly true of our world.
Causal logic must include at least a third option besides "deterministically caused" and "probabilistic-or-random".  This would be a third option, agent causation.  There are infinite possible logics.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/think/article/guide-to-logical-pluralism-for-nonlogicians/EDFDFA1C9EB65DB71848DABD6B1 What logic applies to what aspect of our world is an empirical question.  That we have a three state logic for causation is entirely possible, and exploring possible "agent causation" logic structures until we find one that matches what we have observed of our world is entirely reasonable.

To date, I don't think Doyle or Steward or any other free will advocate I have read has fully nailed an entirely correct logic of agent causation.  However, as noted in the short answer, this is a common problem for philosophy, and therefore not a fatal one. The pursuit of Agent Causation thinking is an active and fruitful Research Programme in philosophy.

+1: Totally with you on the existence of true indeterminacy - the world is not a clock. Also agree that there is some kind of top down causation happening - but I am skeptical it is altogether outside physical causation - quantum field theory would suggest that the naiive view of reductionism fails and that larger fields are not merely superpositions of smaller fields. Finally, I am open to agent causation in terms of something being a free cause, although I don't see how that is different than probabilistic-or-random, its just that we attach that it is attached to an  agent.

+1, but I think that whether we have a logically coherent definition / theory of LFW (which you deny, and which denial I do not dispute), is a different question from whether the concept defies any coherent theory in the first place.  I took the question in the latter sense.

@Annika -- I am a spiritual dualist myself, but tried to write an answer that is compatible with an emergent naturalist ontology as well.  Emergent naturalism breaks the "causal closure" assumption of physicalism.  Popper called his version of this an emergent mind-body dualism, but other advocates of this position (Steward & Doyle among them) are more shy about using the term dualism.

@Dcleve thank you :)

@JohnBollinger correct, even if we grant agent causation as a novel source of causes, I don't see how one, in principle, can explicate how an agent decides that doesn't revert to explanatory chains or brute facts (which are just like random events, each one is a little brute fact)

@Annika We have inclinations to think in certain framings.  The essence of philosophy is to realize that many of the walls we think within are unsupported presuppositions themselves.  That doesn't make them wrong, but they COULD be.  Modern physics discovered that many of our presuppositions do not apply to matter at the micro or macro scales.  Logical pluralism shows that they do not apply to logic.  Me, I am an empiricist, and see loads of reasons to believe we have free will.  That I can't come up with a fully coherent theory for it is -- SOP for much of empirical reality.

@Dcleve - agree. More than happy to have walls torn down but some things seem like a stretch or not sure how I would adjust my thinking to make them make sense.

@JohnBollinger -- We cannot justify any belief or knowledge with logical coherence.  See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64638/is-the-m%c3%bcnchhausen-trilemma-really-a-trilemma/64646#64646 Yet we have beliefs and knowledge.  We have no valid model of time https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/the-passing-of-time/69849#69849 Yet time is a crucial feature of our universe.  I also noted in my answer that we have no complete understanding of causation, yet we use the concept anyway.  This is life as an empiricist!

@Annika -- I was writing part 2 of a reply, and atted JohnBollinger.  Empiricists accept that there are aspects of reality that we don't have valid models for yet.  The ability to be comfortable with incoherence and partial answers is where pragmatic empiricists most dramatically part ways with the dominant analytical movement in philosophy.  That we have significant evidence for free will is decisive.  That our theory is not yet valid does not change that.

Have my upvote, not because I agree, but because your arguments are food for thought. Aside: the link to Cambridge doesn't work, 404 page not found..

@Philomath search for A GUIDE TO LOGICAL PLURALISM FOR NON-LOGICIANS by Zach Weber.


Willed: Brought about by the action of an agent

That definition is way to broad. A stone rolling down a mountain can bring about an action. Though a stone rolling down a mountain is by most accounts an inanimate object without a will. So either you need to hide complexity in the word "agent" idk "a being that can will", which would make that definition circular or you would attribute a will to actions that people would otherwise group as deterministic, which makes this distinction kinda superfluous. Either way that seems to lack crucial information.

Deterministic: An event E is deterministic iff it has at least one sufficient cause

This definition makes it sound as if singular events could be caused by singular causes. And the example with the condiments further points in that direction. The problem is, that is most likely not the case. Singular events like the choice of condiments would not be considered "deterministic", UNLESS, EVERYTHING is deterministic.
Like suppose you have a strong preference for ketchup, you like the texture, the taste, the color and whatnot. Now suppose I change the lighting so that it appears in the most ugly shit and disgusting color you could imagine, suppose I crank up the heat to simmer away the texture and taste, that I mess with the pressure to manipulate your taste buds and whatnot. Would "preference for ketchup" still be a sufficient reason, meaning a reason that if you knew only this you could tell the outcome of the choice 100%, anytime?
Because if you can't then that wouldn't be deterministic, because you the cause you'd identify would be leading, but still not conclusive and sufficient. Meaning while almost predictable, this event would nonetheless be random.
So actual determinism would also require certain lab conditions, those lab conditions require external conditions for the universe and so on, so that in order for any particular event to be deterministic the entire universe and everything in it would need to be deterministic, otherwise it would just be random and the determinism is just an approximation.
So if, as you state:

Random: An event E is random iff it is not deterministic.

Then, as Jo Wehler has mentioned in a comment, you'd include a thing and it's exhaustive opposite so "From Will follows Something or nothing" will be trivially true and also pretty useless as that tells you nothing about what "willed" means or what it particularly entails.
Also as others have already pointed out, if randomness is just indeterminism or non-determinism then this includes a lot more than total arbitrariness. "If under most earthy conditions in the last [your age years] you'd prefer ketchup over everything else", that would be a fairly good approximation to make an educated guess in terms of determining your choice of condiment when faced with a multitude of options. However ultimately it would still be random, because despite that you can't say with 100% certainty that just because ketchup is on the menu it will actually be picked here.
Now the irony is, you can still pick ketchup, you can also pick it because you like it and you can also pick it so often that people think they know you well enough to deduce from "[you] and [ketchup on the menu]" that the amount of ketchup will have shrinked after your meal, yet that's still not a sufficient cause, as libertarian free will still assumes you have a free choice and could decide on a whim to pick something else if you wanted.
Now you could go on as to whether that "want" that desire is ultimately free or whether that desire is determinism creeping in by developing preferences over time through the external influence of the environment, thus making you a product of the environment rather than a free autonomous agent or whether the environment rather restricts the amount of viable options but if, even in a situation where you have just one viable option, your will could still oscillate with respect to how you feel about that option and whether you accept it as your choice or reject it, even though you'd end up doing it either way.
Though with regards to the question, actually you made "random" so broad, that you can fairly easily stuff libertarian free will in that category which makes this not incoherent at least not with your argument.

Let's get more precise and break "random" down further into its 2 possible meanings: (for completeness' sake, if nothing else)

Probabilistic: behaves according to some probability distribution on a fundamental level (many deterministic things follow probability distributions, while they're still non-probabilistic on a fundamental level).
Arbitrary or spontaneous: is not probabilistic and is not determined by causes. It's unclear whether such things are even possible, but let's put that issue aside.

One would also need to define deterministic as being exactly and fully determined by its causes (but maybe this is functionally the same as having a "sufficient cause"). Otherwise this could include behaviour not determined by causes.
Some might also object to the label of "arbitrary or spontaneous", but either way, "deterministic + probabilistic + arbitrary" seems to be an exhaustive list of all possibilities, since "arbitrary" includes anything not included in the first 2 possibilities. Note: I address something being a combination of these things below.

From here, it does indeed seem that libertarian free will doesn't make much sense (although it isn't necessarily incoherent).

Something that is non-deterministic has to be either probabilistic or arbitrary.
Probabilistic and arbitrary things are necessarily free from any influence of our intents, desires, memories, emotions or anything else that makes up our personality.

Proponents of libertarian free will seems to be left with one of the following options:

Accept that "free will" is indeed free from the things that make up our personality. This makes it something that seems to reduce or remove our agency, rather than providing it.
If one says there's "a third thing", aside from deterministic and probabilistic (and which somehow isn't arbitrary), one would seemingly still have to bite the bullet on this point, because being fully determined by intents, desires, memories, etc. is necessarily deterministic.

Assert that there is some part of one's personality that is both meaningful and fundamentally ill-defined.
This position doesn't seem particularly tenable. It would suggest e.g. that you have a meaningful position on whether you like chocolate, yet whether you like chocolate doesn't have a defined value at any given point in time. It seems contradictory.
Note that someone might like chocolate because they like the taste, and might dislike chocolate because it causes undesirable effects because they have lactose intolerance. This is still perfectly consistent with a deterministic view - note that "because" parts above, which provides causal reasoning for those feelings towards chocolate, and that would be well-defined even if those feelings might not boil down to a binary "like"/"dislike" overall feeling towards chocolate.

Define our personality to exist "outside" of ... whatever, such that it's outside of causal consideration.
If one already accepts the existence of some vague underdefined non-physical consciousness (as many people do), adding a vague "free will" to this isn't much of a stretch. But this doesn't solve the problem as much as it just draws an arbitrary line, puts free will on the other side, and only considers what's on this side.


One could also say that any given event breaks down into a combination of deterministic, probabilistic and arbitrary components. But this wouldn't solve the problem with libertarian free will. One could apply this argument for each component, and similarly conclude that the components which aren't deterministic are free from what makes up our personality, and thus they don't provide agency in any meaningful sense. Whereas the ones that are deterministic... are deterministic, which wouldn't do much for the claim of non-deterministic agency.




The similar failure for physicalism even has a name: Hempel's Dilemma.

Hempel's dilemma itself fails because it presupposes the coherence of the non-physical, as I detailed in another answer.

the three preconditions needed for libertarian free will. I consider them to be:
1. Our physical universe is probabilistic. ...

As argued above, probabilistic effects don't seem to provide any reasonable definition of agency. If you pick one thing above another 50% of the time, and there's no rhyme or reason behind that, then the choice is arbitrary. If there is a reason, if it's based on parts of one's personality, then it follows from that, instead of being fundamentally probabilistic.

2. Our physical universe is not causally closed to agents influencing it. Things like the near consensus that irreducibly emergent phenomena are causal, the placebo effect where our awareness is causal, the evolutionary tuning of consciousness, and every one of us experiencing our willing causing our actions every day, make this highly plausibly true of our world.

Questionable claim about consensus aside, this relies on a false dichotomy where consciousness is either "strongly emergent" (something which we have zero verified examples of) or non-physical. And it emphasises the "interaction problem" with both of those views, i.e. how would that interact with the physical world. This isn't an argument against the position that consciousness reduces to brain chemistry (similar to how every other complex system reduces down to its parts). If anything, the 2-way causation between consciousness and the physical world seems to suggest that consciousness exists alongside the things it influences and is influenced by, rather than existing in some other place entirely, in a place people can't explain, and existing in a way people can't explain, and people can't explain how that links back to the physical world to make sense of the aforementioned causal link.

3. Causal logic must include at least a third option besides "deterministically caused" and "probabilistic-or-random". This would be a third option, agent causation.

This is basically just saying that a precondition of libertarian free will is that the coherence of libertarian free will must be shown. Like... yeah, I agree. But the question is whether libertarian free will is coherent. And it seems kinda trivial to say that something must be coherent for us to say it exists. Proponents of libertarian free will presenting that as a meaningful point indicates how little they've got in support of their position, to not even be able to present a positive case for the coherence of their position.

This philosophical notion doesn't depend on knowing the element or mechanism that makes free choice possible. ... The confusion in this question arises because the question presumes a deterministic worldview in which all events must have determinate causal explanations, and so it interprets the concept of 'will' (oddly) as randomness.

The criticism is precisely the lack of any mechanism that could make that make sense, and the apparent contradiction in saying that we have meaningful agency, while implicitly rejecting the notion that said agency is in any way affected by our personality.
Libertarian free will relies on vagueness and handwaving. That could indeed said to be the strength of poorly justified claims (in that it makes it hard or impossible to argue against them). But it's also their weakness, in that you can't justify them, which makes it a good reason to reject such claims.

I think I'm using "random" to cover any case that lacks a set of sufficient cause. Note: a sufficient cause can be a set of conditions -- I'm not suggesting determinism == "billiard ball causation".

+1 also as I think you've hit on what I think is the incoherent part. Incoherence is holding views that do not hang together. Therefore, holding onto the concept of "free will being neither determined nor random" while being unable to explicate exactly what about it avoids randomness or determinism is incoherent.

There is not much difference between arbitrary and probabilistic in your terminology. Suppose you have a coin that has a 99% chance of landing on heads. It then lands on heads. Why did it land on heads? You can’t just say because it had a 99% chance, for it had a 1% chance of landing on tails. There is no cause or reason behind why it landed on heads. If there is, it effectively becomes deterministic. Both those options are essentially random.

Arguably though, anything that has a defined constant probabilistic distribution likely isn’t random in the first place. It’s why even coins are deterministic under the hood and why if I had to gamble, quantum mechanics is also operating under determinism

@Syed "There is not much difference between arbitrary and probabilistic" - the difference is that something with a 1% chance reliably shows up 1% of the time (even though we don't know when exactly that would happen). Whereas something that's arbitrary has no consistent frequency, or it might be a one-time event that we had no reason to think was even possible prior to it happening.

But do you really need to define arbitrary when you have probabilistic?  One way to model this is everything is in the probabilistic list but it may just be sufficiently low probability as to be unlikely.  That would cover things you might want to put in the arbitrary list. I think the model you are proposing is things that have happened before are in the probabilistic list and things that haven't are in the arbitrary list since we weren't aware of their possibility. But then things we aren't aware of make it hard to define and reason about. Just like it's hard to enumerate the arbitrary list.

"something with a 1% chance reliably shows up 1% of the time" -- only in the limit of an infinite number of trials.  I don't know about you, but I'm not prepared to wait that long.  Anything that reliably happens 1% of the time in a finite number of trials has at least a degree of determinism.

I think the creation of "arbitrary" is the point... If there were no option (to an outside observer) for an event to be neither "determined" nor "probabilistic", then there is no way to distinguish "willed" behaviour anyway.


Willed: Brought about by the action of an agent 
Deterministic: An event E is deterministic iff it has at least one sufficient cause 
Random: An event E is random iff it is not deterministic.

There are some problems here. First, you are defining randomness to be anything not deterministic. But in libertarian free will it is supposed there is a third option, so it's not proper to just assume there isn't. And in fact, in mathematics, there are other options. Mathematically, "randomness" just means something using one particular abstract structure out of infinite possible others - the abstract structure of random variables. And for that matter, "deterministic" in mathematics also means a certain kind of abstract structure that involves time-varying states which depend on previous states. There are plenty of other structures than those two!
For example, a causal filter could be taken as a simplified model of determinism. A filter in this context is a transformation applied to a time-varying input signal to produce a time-varying output signal. A filter is causal if the output depends only on inputs from the past or present.
But non-causal filters aren't random! Like causal filters, they're the result of applying a formula to obtain a definite output. For non-causal filters, this formula just involves terms from the future. Would you say non-causal filters are deterministic? That doesn't seem right. They're determined by a formula, but unlike what we normally think of as "deterministic," their next state is not determined by past states.
Now, I'm not saying that libertarian free will involves some sort of influence from the future; this was just an example to show that there are more options than just "deterministic" and "random."
I'm also not saying libertarian free will makes sense. Yes, our choices, when we introspect, do seem to be caused by our mental state - our beliefs and preferences. And if they weren't caused by our mental state, we would seem to ourselves to be acting randomly - we wouldn't be in control! That would be quite upsetting to us. To be in control is nothing more than for our conscious preferences to determine our actions.

I'm not too familiar with the concept, but it seems non-causal filters can be viewed as only non-causal with respect to the past/present. They depend on future inputs, which makes those future inputs the cause.

@NotThatGuy You can use the word "causal" any way you like, but usually we use it to mean something where what we call a "cause" precedes what we call an "effect." Same for deterministic, where for something to be called "deterministic" it implies that the next state is determined by temporally preceding states.

We can call it something else, e.g. "future-causal" - I don't mind. The question would then be whether future-causation provides a meaningful resolution to incoherency of libertarian free will. I don't see how it does. Except that future-causation would get very convoluted very quickly, and people might become convinced that the answer is hidden somewhere in that complexity (even if there isn't any fundamental reason why it would be).

@NotThatGuy It doesn't provide any resolution to that; as I said in my answer I am not saying libertarian free will makes sense. The purpose of the example is simply to demonstrate an example of something non-random and non-causal.

You ask if libertarian free will is incoherent.
The problem is that you strawman the position of libertarian free will.
You state that something willed is either willed in a deterministic way or by random chance. That is simply not the libertarian position. To then prove that your strawman is incoherent doesn't prove anything.
Libertarianism states that determinism is incompatible with free will and since agents have free will, determinism must be false. This is perfectly coherent in itself. Then of course, as a libertarian, you have to explain how agents exercise free will and that's where the trouble for libertarians starts.
I don't think we have any free will whatsoever.

Thanks - the incoherent part is what is free will and does the prima facie plausibility of it really hold up under logical scrutiny. I don't think it does as a freely willing agent is an incoherent idea -- to the extent it is expressing will it is deterministic, to the extent it is allowing freedom it is random. Deliberation is just a series of related throughts to get to a decisoin - we can fully accoomodate that without posulating a new form of causality

You ask if a married bachelor is incoherent. The problem is that you strawman the position of married bachelors. You state that someone is either a bachelor or married. That is simply not the married bachelor position. To then prove that your strawman is incoherent doesn't prove anything.

Libertarian free will is not incoherent. Only your strawman of libertarian free will is.
Your fallacy is wrong dichotomy. Deterministic vs. random is a wrong dichotomy for multiple reasons:

There are no deterministic events in reality. Determinism is not an option.
The opposite of deterministic is indeterministic, not random.
The opposite of random is deliberate.

The real dichotomy is deliberate vs. random. Libertarian free will is the ability to make deliberate choices in the absence of determinism.

"The opposite of deterministic is indeterministic, not random."  By definition (ie An event E is random iff it is not deterministic) random IS indeterministic. And deliberate is the same thing as willed.  This is just an argument over semantics.  It doesn't change the OPs position or prove Libertarian free will is or isn't incoherent.

That definition of yours is the wrong dichotomy. Random is indeterministic but it is not the only thing that is indeterministic. Determinism excludes not only randomness, but also all cognitive functions like deliberation. Libertarian free will cannot be proven or disproven. It is not a claim or a theory.

The core issue is that when talking about decisions and responsibility of admissible agents (e.g. humans), agents are considered indivisible (without a formal delineation of a single agent). As such any formal reasoning just breaks down in the extremes:

When a person kills another while sleepwalking, who is responsible?
At what age is a human responsible and can go to jail?
Can a person with identity dissociation (aka multiple personalities) be responsible and non-reapinsible at the same time?
Can humanity as a whole be held responsible for climate change? How does that responsibility trickle down to people living in harmony with nature, or babies?
What non-humans (animals, computers, plants) can carry responsibility?

The flavor of libertarian free will that entrenches itself on the matter of responsibility posits an indivisible self that makes the decision, magically. Like an eternal soul.
At the lastest since the introductions of computer, philosophy however had to deal with the possibility that all humans as agents have a mind that is divisible and works in separate independent processes. And brain research found out different parts of the brain apparently being influential in different parts of that process.
And that causes the coherence issue, there is a concept of decisions and responsibility that works only with agents as indivisible entities, and there is an apparent reality of agents being divisible "machines".
Compatibilism does not conflict with that, it allows for certain machines to be philosophically valid bearers of responsibility (though maybe not legally with current laws, laws still need to catch up with technology).
But libertarians believe that if agents are divisible in any way (even say if in a magic fairy dimension of souls and rainbows where all real decisions are made, souls were divisible into smaller parts), responsibility as a concept falls part, and society will break apart, and there will be rape and murder and pillaging since nothing matters anymore. That's why it's important for libertarian free will that something exists that is indivisible and makes decisions and bears responsibility.
So the issue of libertarian free will is not just that a decision must be made independently of prior states of the universe, but also that the agent of decisions is indivisible, in contrast to how computers or theoretical neural networks work.
That does not make libertarian free will incoherent, it is rather a form of wishful thinking that is not theoretically impossible, but at odds with all we know already about brains, minds and computers.
